# Add a additional elements to service that are missing from WSDL in suds

Tags: python, wsdl, suds

I am using suds to access an API using Python. I have suds working correctly, building the envelope using `client.factory.create()`.

I just found out from the developers of this other API that the WSDL is incomplete, and missing a half dozen required fields.

Is there any way to add the fields to the object after I create it with `client.factory.create`?  Or do I have to scrap the WSDL and do it all by hand?

(I know the proper thing would be for them to fix the WSDL, but I don't have any control over that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be a problem to add additional fields to an object that is created using factory.create()

```
obj = client.factory.create('ns1:object')
obj.newField = 'value'
```

The obj should now have all the fields from the WSDL, and the newField.

Comment: I swear I tried exactly that, and kept getting a TypeError.  I just tried it again though, and it worked perfectly, so it was most likely some other mistake I made.  Thanks!